# Merging columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, merge

I have the following data frame,

```
c1 <- c(1,2,"<NA>","<NA>")
c2 <- c("<NA>","<NA>",3,4)
df <- data.frame(c1,c2)

>df 

    c1   c2
1    1 <NA>
2    2 <NA>
3 <NA>    3
4 <NA>    4
```

The following is the desired output that I'm trying to obtain after merging columns 1 ,2

```
  >df 

    c1  
1    1 
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

I tried,

```
df <- mutate(df, x =paste(c1,c2))
```

which gives

```
> df
    c1   c2      x
1    1 <NA> 1 <NA>
2    2 <NA> 2 <NA>
3 <NA>    3 <NA> 3
4 <NA>    4 <NA> 4
```

Could someone give suggestions on how to obtain the desired output?

Comment: If the '<NA>' strings are actually NA values (rather than strings) you could also use `coalesce(c1, c2)` (from `dplyr`)

Comment: Are you looking for a `<NA>` strings or `NA`?

Comment: I'm looking at NA not <NA> strings.Sorry, if my original question wasn't clear

Comment: @VladC. using coalesce ,is it possible to retain the row index from the original data frame?

Comment: @Natasha: If you use `coalesce` inside `mutate`, that should not affect the row index. I added that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems the the dataframe actually contains `NA` values rather than `'<NA>'` strings, I would suggest to use `coalesce`:

```
c1 <- c(1,2,NA, NA)
c2 <- c(NA, NA,3,4)
df <- data.frame(c1,c2)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(c3=coalesce(c1, c2))
```

Output:

```
   c1 c2 c3
1  1 NA  1
2  2 NA  2
3 NA  3  3
4 NA  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is this:

```
c1 <- c(1, 2, NA, NA)
c2 <- c(NA, NA, 3, 4)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)

df2 <- data.frame(
  c1 = ifelse(is.na(df$c1), df$c2, df$c1)
)

#df2
#  c1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you are pasting together two strings where one uses the string NA in angled brackets to represent nothing, and if you are pasting strings together and want a string to not appear in the pasted string you need to have it as a zero length string.  You can do this using the `recode` command in `dplyr`.

You can modify your code to be:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, x =paste0(recode(c1,"<NA>" = ""),recode(c2,"<NA>" = "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `dplyr` from `tidyverse`:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(c3 = if_else(is.na(c1),c2,c1)) %>% 
    select(-c1, -c2) %>% # Given you only wanted one column
    rename(c1 = c3) # Given you wanted the column to be called c1
```

Output:

```
  c1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowSums` :

```
data.frame(c1 = rowSums(df,na.rm = TRUE))
#   c1
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 4  4
```